# How to get response data from golang backend through @angular/http?

Tags: angular, http, typescript, go, beego

The fronted typescript code is:

```
signIn(signInCredential: SignInCredential): Promise<any> {
    //Build the form package
    let queryParam:string = 'principal=' + encodeURIComponent(signInCredential.principal) +
    '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(signInCredential.password);
    //Trigger Http
    return this.http.post(signInUrl, queryParam, { headers: this.formHeaders })
        .toPromise()
        .then(() => null)
        .catch(error => this.handleError(error));      
}
```

The backend golang code is:

```
func (cc *CommonController) Login() []byte {
    group := ColorGroup{
        ID:     1,
        Name:   "Reds",
        Colors: []string{"Crimson", "Red", "Ruby", "Maroon"},
    }
    data, err := json.Marshal(group)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    return data
}
```

The angular router is:

```
beego.Router("/login", &controllers.CommonController{}, "post:Login")
```

How can I get the data returned by the Login() in the http.post of typescipt?

Thanks for all reply!

Comment: You must register *response handler* in `then` function instead of `()=>null`. Take a look at [https://angular.io/guide/http#promises](https://angular.io/guide/http#promises).

Comment: @putu Thanks for your guide! I have solved the problem.